# Select one item in three RadionButtonList?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can I select one item in three RadionButtonList ?Currently I'm using SelectedIndexChanged and set the RadionButtonList.SelectedIndex into -1, if it's not selected.

Problem: it's a little bit slow to select another RadionButtonList.
Please help me to make it faster using javascript. Thanks in advance.

I'm using: vb .net & asp .net

Browser: IE 11

**SELECTION 1:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkYr2012S1" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkYr2012S1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
<asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkArchive" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkArchive_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
<asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>



<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkCurrent" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkCurrent_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**SELECTION 2:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkYr2012S2" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkYr2012S2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
<asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkArchive2" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkArchive2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
<asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>



<asp:RadioButtonList ID="chkCurrent2" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="chkCurrent2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P10" Value="P10"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P2" Value="P2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P5" Value="P5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P8" Value="P8"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P11" Value="P11"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P3" Value="P3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P6" Value="P6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P9" Value="P9"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":P12" Value="P12"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

---

```
Protected Sub chkYr2012S1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkYr2012S1.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkArchive.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkCurrent.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Protected Sub chkArchive_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkArchive.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkYr2012S1.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkCurrent.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Protected Sub chkCurrent_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkCurrent.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkYr2012S1.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkArchive.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Protected Sub chkYr2012S2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkYr2012S2.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkArchive2.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkCurrent2.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Protected Sub chkArchive2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkArchive2.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkYr2012S2.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkCurrent2.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Protected Sub chkCurrent2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkCurrent2.SelectedIndexChanged
        chkYr2012S2.SelectedIndex = -1
        chkArchive2.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jQuery.

First a function that allows only one RadioButton to be checked, and removes the other checked radiobuttons because you cannot "uncheck" them yourself. For this to work, wrap the RadioButtonLists in an element with a unique identifier. In this case `RadioButtonListContainer`

```
<div id="RadioButtonListContainer">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P1" Value="P1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P4" Value="P4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text=":P7" Value="P7"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

Then the function that allows only one radio to be checked in all three RadioButtonLists

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#RadioButtonListContainer input').change(function () {
            $('#RadioButtonListContainer input').each(function (idx, ele) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Next you need a CustomValidator to check if there is at least one radio checked in all three RadioButtonLists.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="checkRadioButtonList"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadioButtonList(sender, args) {
        var isValid = false;

        $('#RadioButtonListContainer input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        });

        args.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @VDWWD, thanks for your response but when I checked one item from **Checkboxlist #1** and checked also one item from **Checkboxlist #2**, **Checkboxlist #1** checked item must unchecked. On my **third select** the first item got unchecked. look strange.